# why is git pull request not working and i always get errors?

Tags: github

when i use git pull command I came with an error as below
[image: image showing error]

Comment: Please include the contents of the console at a cdiblock in your question instead of a screenshot. Optionally add the screenshot in addition to the actual text. The screenshot can't be indexed making it hard for other people with the same issue to find your question and possible solutions for the problem.

Comment: The title mentions that creating a pull request isn't working, but `git pull` doesn't create a pull request. Can you try to explain better what you are trying to accomplish in the question body?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an active & tracking branch to pull from, As of this moment, you don’t have one set up.

To confirm an active & track a branch:

> git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/‹branch› main

More Information on git pull:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-pull-explained/amp/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to pull from an unknown branch.

You can try pull from master branch

```
git pull origin master
```

Or you can pair your local master branch with remote master branch using

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

After setting upstream, normal "*git pull*" command will work. You don't have to specify branch name with "*git pull*".

Comment: Thank you so much but when I did that it says it is already up to date but it's still not updated on my local ide..

Comment: Have you cloned the repository that is hosted on your GitHub? That's the repository that will pull the changes from GitHub.